# i want to send dynamic textbox and file upload value using form data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, smarty

i want to send dynamic textbox and file upload value using form data 
Example like variablename="string1=string1.jpg+string2=string2.jpg+string3=string3.jpg"

**javascript**

```
 $("#addRow").click(function () {
                for(var i=0;i<1;i++){
            $("#dynamicadd").append("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-8'><div class='form-group'><input type='text' class='form-control'  id='field-3"+ counter +"'  placeholder=''></div></div><div class='col-md-4'><div class='form-group'><div class='fileUpload btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light' style='margin-top:0;'><span>Upload</span><input type='file'  name='uploadBtn' id='uploadBtn' class='upload'/></div></div></div></div>");
              }
              counter++;
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your dynamicadd is in form element.
Use below code to submit form with file(s) element with ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: your url here,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: new FormData(jQuery('#your-form-id')[0]), 
    success: function(response) {
     }
});
```

Comment: i want to get all value in alertbox like

Comment: "string1=string1.jpg+string2=string2.jpg+string3=string3.jpg"

Comment: @RamnikRangpariya what is your exact requirement ? can you specify ?